# Blazor Client Side Enable Cache

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

When my blazor application first starts on the server, it loads a lot of dlls and when I look at the headers of the dlls, it says no-cache, so it doesn't load cache, so I have to wait every time I open the page. How can I activate the cache feature?

Comment: Production or Development are you seeing this?